# Openx 2.8.7 geotargeting does not work

Tags: openx

I'm not able to make Openx geotargeting work - I have enabled geotargeting as described here: http://www.openx.com/docs/2.8/adminguide/Global%20settings%20-%20geotargeting, but no luck, my test banner it's still not delivered. Did someone succeeded to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works for me. A couple of more things to check, besides the maxmind configuration:

1. If you have a cluster all the machines used for delivery should have the geotargeting properly configured.
2. When testing your banners be sure that you are not using an internal IP - for example when I'm connected to my company network I receive an IP which does not exist in maxmind database (and the geolocation will not work). If your openx machine and your test server is inside of the same network you may have this problem too.